# Is it legal or safe to depend on the ordering of URL query parameters?

Tags: http, url, url-parameters

Is it legal or safe to depend on the ordering of URL query parameters?  Specifically, would I be able to write code, and trust that that code will always work, that had different behavior based on these two query strings:

```
?a=10&add=5&multiply=3    # might mean (10 + 5) * 3
?a=10&multiply=3&add=5    # might mean (10 * 3) + 5
```

(My example is of course contrived, I know it's ridiculous to build a calculator like this. :) )

Comment: Side note: if you don't specify parhentesis I suggest to rely on PEMDAS, at least you'll have correct math

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those query strings are both perfectly legal and distinct. According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), the query string is nothing more than

> ...non-hierarchical data that... serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority

The rules for how HTML forms must generate `key=value` pairs in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format are detailed [in the W3C HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm). Of particular interest are the rules for how to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content:

> To decode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payloads, the following algorithm should be used....
>
> The output of this algorithm is a **sorted** list of name-value pairs.

Therefore, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` query string content may be correctly regarded as a sorted list of key/value pairs.

**However**, bear in mind that not all Web frameworks capture this information. They may instead provide you with an unordered dictionary of property names and values parsed from the query string. For example, the [`url.parse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) method in Node.js returns a parsed query string as an object (whose properties are the key/value` pairs), and JavaScript objects are always unordered.